# How to check the coding rules in sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube5.1.2

I have my project on my computer which is qt-project(.pro file) written in C++, will it read this type of file?

I loaded the project on to sonarqube using sonar-runner and using the c++ plugin for languages. The result show the code has no errors even though we gave it a code with errors. The only thing it shows is Complexity, Dulpications and Lines of Code.